# Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) When Upgrading Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, localhost

I just tried to upgrade the latest wordpress version, and it throws this error. 
Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) . I immediately communicated it to the service provider, they say it is a database error. But i checked the wp-config file with correct database name, username and password, It is all perfect. But why still im getting the same error, Its a server problem or anything has corrupted while upgrading the wordpress version.

Comment: clear your cache in the server

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons for having such problems:

- Hosting provider problems
- Wrong DB info in wp-config
- A hostname issue. Are you using *localhost* as a `DB_HOST`? Some hosting companies do not work with *localhost*. See [codex reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Set_Database_Host) for more.
- Database tables need repair/optimization. Wordpress has an in built functionality [to achieve this](https://www.maketecheasier.com/fix-corrupted-wordpress-database-2/).
- Changes in the way wordpress handles databases. [Similar post and solution](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/access-denied-for-user-localhost-using-password-no#post-6997701).

In your case I would go with the last one, as you say that the issue came up after the update